# How do I find out what color mode an image is in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, color-spaces

I am using one image. I just want to know in which format it is: CMYK or RGB? How do I find this out in Illustrator?

Comment: You mean for a placed image?

Answer (score 5):

You can go to *File* > *Document Color Mode* and the current color mode will have a checkmark next to it. You can switch between color modes in this menu.

Answer (score 1):

It states the colour model in the tab at the top of the window; it should say something along the lines of 'MyFile.ai @50% (RGB/Preview)' on the tab for every file you have open.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what color mode and image is on illustrator use your link panel. I am currently working on a brochure and my color mode on illustrator is set to CMYK, however you can still have images in your document that are in RGB mode.

Open your Link panel by going to Window and scroll down to Links. Then find the image in your links panel that you want to check and double click it this will open information about that image. like so [image]
[image]

Under COLOR SPACE you can see that it says my image is in RGB. 
That means i will have to open this file in photoshop and convert it to CMYK.

the same would be true if you needed an RGB file and your link panel says your file was in CMYK format.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at color modes in detail.

Before starting a new illustration, you should decide which color mode the artwork
should use, CMYK or RGB.

• CMYK—Cyan, magenta, yellow, and black are the colors used in four-color
process printing. These four colors are combined and overlapped in a screen
pattern to create a multitude of other colors. Select this mode for printing.

• RGB—Red, green, and blue light are added together in various ways to create
an array of colors. Select this mode if you are using images for on-screen
presentations or the Internet.

When creating a new document, you select a color mode by choosing File > New
and picking the appropriate document Profile, such as Print, which uses CMYK for
the color mode. You can change the color mode by clicking the arrow to the left of
Advanced and making a selection in the Color Mode menu.

[image]

When a color mode is selected, the applicable panels open, displaying colors in the
selected color mode. You can change the color mode of a document, after a file is
created, by choosing File > Document Color Mode and then selecting either CMYK
or RGB in the menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on Window > Document Info. A panel will appear that shows not only which color mode (CMYK or RGB) but will also show the profile (eg Coated Fogra). People often get confused between the two.